# How to convert datetime values from rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

```
Starttime                   Shift
--------------------------------------------
2019-11-21 10:36:11.393      1 
2019-11-21 10:38:22.590      1
2019-11-21 10:40:32.940      1
2019-11-21 10:36:11.393      2
2019-11-21 10:38:45.407      2
```

I need result

```
Shift     Starttime1               starttime2                 starttime3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       2019-11-21 10:36:11.393    2019-11-21 10:38:22.590  2019-11-21 10:40:32.940 
2       2019-11-21 10:36:11.393    2019-11-21 10:38:45.407
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select 
    shift,
    max(case when rn = 1 then starttime end) starttime1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then starttime end) starttime2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then starttime end) starttime3
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by shift order by starttime) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by shift
```